# ¿Cómo configurar un servicio para mostrar Spinner de ionic 6 cuando se haga una petición http?

Tags: angular, ionic

Estoy intentando implementar un `servicio` con los métodos de `ionic 6` para abrir y cerrar un Spinner. Esto lo utilizaría cuando haga una petición http en mi proyecto, de momento medio funciona, porque si lo agrego en un `setTimeOut` de 5s el Spinner tarda en cerrarse, se queda colgado o no se muestra.

Les comparto el código, que por cierto, sólo he dejado lo esencial, he quitado servicios, decoradores y otros elementos que no considero relevante para el tema principal.

Mi archivo TS:

```js
import { HttpGenericService } from '../../../services/http-generic.service';
import { IonLoaderService } from 'src/app/services/ion-loader.service';

export class AsociadosPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private _generic: HttpGenericService<any>,
  ) {
    
  }
  
  guardarPersona2() {
    const data = this.formPersonas.value;
    
    if (data.id !== null) {
    
      setTimeout(() => {
        this._ionLoader.simpleLoader(); // Abrir Spinner
        
        this._generic.update('/asociados/personas', data.id, data).subscribe(resp => {
          
          console.log(resp);
          console.log('Datos Actualizados');
          
          this._ionLoader.dismissLoader(); // cerrar spinner
          
          this.menuController.close('custom');
          this.getPersonas();
        });
      }, 5000);
      
    } else {
      this._generic.post('/asociados/personas', data).subscribe(resp => {
        console.log(resp);
      });
    }
  }

}
```

Mi Spinner Services:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';

export class IonLoaderService {

  constructor(public loadingController: LoadingController) { }

  // Simple loader - Mostrar y Cerrar Mensaje de carga
  async simpleLoader() {
    await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Cargando...'
    }).then((response) => {
      response.present();
      response.dismiss();
    });
  }

  // Dismiss loader
  async dismissLoader() {
    await this.loadingController.dismiss().then((response) => {
      console.log('Loader closed!', response);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error occured : ', err);
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Error

El principal error es que `setTimeout` contiene tanto el abrir el loader como la llamada.

```js
setTimeout(()=>{
  this._ionLoader.simpleLoader();
  this._generic.update ....
},5000)
```

La razón del porque a veces se muestra y otras veces no puede ser porque la llamada se hace demasiado rápido, por lo que no le da tiempo a hacer cambios en el DOM

#### Solución

Crearemos un método que sea `dismissLoaderSlow`

```js
dismissLoaderSlow() {
   setTimeout(() => {
     this.dismissLoader()
   },500);
}
```

Y quitamos el `setTimeout` del componente